# difficulties (bugs?) with kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

i'm new to KineticJS, the documentation is poor so I'm having a bit of difficulty making work these two examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/jure/xUEse/

http://jsfiddle.net/jure/jgrpx/

What's wrong with them?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why the first mouse move gives undefined, but you if statement should be `if(p!="undefined")` or `if(typeof p!=undefined)` and not `if(typeof p!="undefined")`.